# How to iter over a kivy DictProperty

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to use kivys `DictObject` and reuse the same object in other screens, but i it seems that i am missing an important feature, especially iterating over the DictObject. Here is my code:

```
test_data = {1: "hello", 2: "world"}


class AlarmScreen(Screen):      
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.printItems(mainApp.alarmLib)            

    def printItems(self, givenDict):
        for i in givenDict:
            print(i)  

class mainApp(App):
    alarmLib = DictProperty()

    def build(self):       
        self.alarmLib = test_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

Unfortunatly printItems results in a

```
TypeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object is not iterable
```

I tryed it with enumerate(), items(), but that doesnt work eighter. So can i use the DictObject for working with a dictonary through multiple screens or do i need to create an "old" dict object with

```
def __init__(self, givenDict):
    self.giveDict = givenDict
```

for that?

Thank you for the hint in advance.

Comment: You are accessing the class. You need to access the instance.

Comment: I suppose you can use `.get()` and `.set()` to access the value of any Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mainApp.alarmLib is a DictProperty with a name=alarmLib. Need to define the constructor ( __init__ ) method.
2. Display the DictProperty as follow:

## Snippet

```
for key in givenDict:
    print("key={0}, value={1}".format(key, givenDict[key]))
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


test_data = {1: "hello", 2: "world"}


class AlarmScreen(Screen):
    parmDict = DictProperty({})

    def __init__(self, parmDict, **kwargs):
        super(AlarmScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parmDict = parmDict

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.printItems(self.parmDict)

    def printItems(self, givenDict):
        for key in givenDict:
            print("key={0}, value={1}".format(key, givenDict[key]))


class mainApp(App):
    alarmLib = DictProperty({})

    def build(self):
        self.alarmLib = test_data
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(AlarmScreen(name='alarmscreen', parmDict=self.alarmLib))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - DictProperty Displayed]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I create my screenmanager in the .kv file. I added your suggested __init__ to mainApp and created then an instance. `mainApp(App):
    alarmLib = DictProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, alarmLib, **kwargs):
        super(mainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.alarmLib = alarmLib

    def build(self):   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = mainApp({})
    myApp.run()` i can then work with the variable as i wanted.

Comment: I tried to implement the same code for my use case but to make it work I removed the {} from the declaration

Comment: @user13662507: The code ran successfully using the latest stable and dev kivy on Linux. Thank you for feedback.